# Telerik RadGrid Virtualization and GridClientSelectColumn

Tags: telerik, virtualization, radgrid

Telerik came out with a new version of its controls (Q3 2013) that supports Virtulization in it's radgrid.  This works great for 300,000 records, but I am having trouble being able to "select all" records using the GridClientSelectColumn.  When you click the "select all" button in the header, it selects however many records are in your page view.  This is going to be confusing to the end users....On a positive note, it looks like the selected records are persisted (client side?) as the user navigates from one page to the next and back.  Anyone have any ideas or suggestions how to make it look like the user can "select all records" instead of just all records in the view?